# HtmlUnit com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error

Tags: java

```
 List <HtmlElement> ips = null ;
 List <HtmlElement> ports = null ; 
 ArrayList <String> proxies = new ArrayList();
 HtmlPage page = null;
 String baseUrl = "http://www.freeproxylists.net/" ;
 WebClient client;

 try{
 client = new WebClient();
 client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
 page = client.getPage(baseUrl);
 ips = page.getByXPath("//table[@class='DataGrid']/tbody/tr/td[position()=1]/text()");
 ports = page.getByXPath("//table[@class='DataGrid']/tbody/tr/td[position()=2]/text()");

 for(int i=0;i<ips.size();i++){
 proxies.add(ips.get(i)+":"+ports.get(i));
 System.out.println(ips.get(i)+":"+ports.get(i));
 }


 }
 catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println(e);
 }
```

**sorry for my bad code indenting, anyway i'm trying to scrape proxy from the site and i got these warning:**

mag 20, 2018 4:04:56 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
AVVERTENZA: CSS error: 'http://www.freeproxylists.net/grid.css' [1:1] Error in rule. (Invalid token "<". Was expecting one of: , , "", ".", ":", "*", "[", , , , , , , .)
mag 20, 2018 4:04:56 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
AVVERTENZA: CSS warning: 'http://www.freeproxylists.net/grid.css' [1:1] Ignoring the whole rule.
mag 20, 2018 4:04:56 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
AVVERTENZA: CSS error: 'http://www.freeproxylists.net/grid.css' [45:1] Error in rule. (Invalid token "<". Was expecting one of: , , "", ".", ":", "*", "[", , , , , , .)
mag 20, 2018 4:04:56 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
AVVERTENZA: CSS warning: 'http://www.freeproxylists.net/grid.css' [45:1] Ignoring the whole rule.

**How can i fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace the DefaultCssErrorHandler used by your WebClient with the SilentCssErrorHandler.

The HtmlUnit [FAQ](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#SilentCssErrorHandler) page has a short sample for this.